# Strategies for preventing Maven from connecting to an external repository when it doesn't need to

Tags: maven, nexus

I work within a very large enterprise that is reasonably paranoid about security. We have an enterprise Maven repository that mirrors central and other external repositories.

We are attempting to use an artifact whose source is on github, and which specifies its artifact repository is oss.sonatype.org.  The main artifact has one dependency, developed by the same group, also on github, and also on oss.sonatype.org.  Our mirror of central has both of those artifacts.  I'm deliberately not mentioning the artifact, although it's probably not necessary.  It's likely used by many other companies.

We have a service that specifies the first artifact as a dependency.  When the build runs, it is able to get the artifact from our internal mirror.  However, it also attempts to connect to oss.sonatype.org to see if it can find the artifacts there also.  However, we intentionally do not have a proxy setting in our settings.xml file, which effectively prevents attempts to get artifacts from external repositories.  This functionally works.  We get the artifact from our internal mirror, not from the external repository.

However, what happens in this case is that the connection attempt to oss.sonatype.org, takes a long time, only to give up when it fails.  It apparently attempts this connection quite a few times.  In fact, when we tested a build with a customized settings.xml that DID set a proxy, we found that this ran two orders of magnitude faster than the one that times out the connection each time.  Ironically, even though the build with the proxy goes much faster, it still fails to connect to oss.sonatype.org, with 401 errors (which is odd, as I though it allows anon access).  This is not a problem, as we're getting the artifacts from our internal mirror, and with the proxy set, we simply get the 401 error much much quicker than without the proxy.

So, is there some way we can configure our Maven builds, such that when it gets the initial artifact, it simply gets both artifacts from our internal mirror, without attempting a connection to oss.sonatype.org, and very importantly, not changing the original artifacts at all?

**Update**:

I've examined the information about "mirrors" cited in the comment.  Our setttings.xml in our CI server already has one mirror specification, which is approximately the following:

```
    <mirror>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
        <url>https://.../nexus/content/groups/...-public-group</url>
    </mirror>
```

If it helps, our intranet repository is Nexus.

It's not clear what additional mirror specifications I have to add to ensure that repository references to oss.sonatype.org go to our intranet repository instead.

Comment: You can tell maven in your pom.xml that it is to use a mirror and only that.  http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html#using-a-single-repository